# Functor instance with recursive data constructor

Tags: haskell, recursion, functor

I am having trouble implementing a recursive functor instance. I have tried as follow, but I receive an error that cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ List b

```
data List a = Hol x a| Hoofd x [List a]
            deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
instance Functor List where
            fmap f Hol x a = Hol x (f a)
            fmap f (Hoofd x rest) = Hoofd x (fmap f rest)
```

How to fix this and what's my problem?

Answer (score 3):

The `fmap` will work on the list, so perform a mapping. This means that you use `f :: a -> b` to convert a `List a -> List b`, which will not work: you need another functor mapping, so:

```
instance Functor List where
    fmap f (Hol x a) = Hol x (f a)
    fmap f (Hoofd x rest) = Hoofd x (fmap (fmap f) rest)
```

or we can work with a helper function:

```
instance Functor List where
    fmap f = go
        where go (Hol x a) = Hol x (f a)
              go (Hoofd x rest) = Hoofd x (fmap go rest)
```

Or we can work with the [**`Compose`** type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) to perform a mapping that is two (or more) layers deep:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose(Compose(getCompose))

instance Functor List where
    fmap f (Hol x a) = Hol x (f a)
    fmap f (Hoofd x xs) = Hoofd x (getCompose (fmap f (Compose xs)))
```

or you can generalize the `List` type, as [@amalloy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145990/haskell-functor-instance-with-recursive-data-constructor#comment129189780_73146026), with:

```
import Data.Functor.Compose(Compose)

data List f a = Hol X a | Hoofd X (Compose f (List f) a)
    deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

instance Functor f => Functor (List f) where
    fmap f (Hol x a) = Hol x (f a)
    fmap f (Hoofd x rest) = Hoofd x (fmap f rest)
```

Comment: If you were going to use Compose, I think it would be nicer to use it in the data type definition: `data List a = Hol x a| Hoofd x (Compose [] List a)`. Then to implement `fmap` you can just call `fmap`.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting generalizing List, just using `Compose [] List a` instead of `[List a]`. I think you've generalized it all the way to the free monad (except the dangling `X` values), so I'm not sure it's even right to call it List anymore.